# How is it possible to initially set a progress bar to not be visible, then appear on a click?

Tags: html

I've got some h and img elements which are children of a li. When the user clicks on the li I want to hide these and make a progress bar appear. I have the appearing/disappearing of the items working but don't know how to set the progress bar to initially not be shown.

Here's the code:

```
    <li id="li1"">
    <img id = "track_image" src="image.jpg" />
    <h1 id = "track_title">Title</h1>
    <h2 id = "artist_name">Name"</h2>
    <audio id="audio1"></audio>
    div id="progressBar"><span id="progress"></span></div>
    </li>


function audioClick(evt, listElementId, audioId, clip) {
    var listElement = document.getElementById(listElementId);
    var title = listElement.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
    hideOrShowElement(title);
    var artist = listElement.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
    hideOrShowElement(artist);
    var date = listElement.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
    hideOrShowElement(date);

    var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.src = clip;
        audio.play();
    }
    else {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
}

function hideOrShowElement(element) {
    if(element.style.display == 'none')
        element.style.display = 'block';
    else
        element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

I want to add a progress bar when the audio plays, so was thinking of incorporating the progress bar here

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2

But I don't know how to initially set it so that its not displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this on page load

```
var ProgressBar = document.getElementById("progressbar");
elem.style.display = "none";
```

and on click

```
ProgressBar.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the adobe link's css then just change the display of #progress to be none initially:

```
#progress {
 background-color:#ff0000; // red
 height:20px;
 display:none;
}
```